# How to get to the public directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) in my project, and I want to use a global image - my website logo image.

As I understand the `public` directory at the root of the project (which `angular-cli` created) is for public assets - which seems like a good place to put my image (please correct me if I'm wrong).

But, when I try to get to that image in my `<img src="/public/book4u-logo.svg" />` tag, I get 404. The reason is, of course, my project root is the `src` directory and not the project root directory.

So, how should I get to that directory? Or should I place my image in another directory?

My project tree (i remove the unnecessary suff):

```
.
├── angular-cli-build.js
├── angular-cli.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── book4u-logo.svg
│   └── hero-image-default.jpg
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── bfy.component.html
│   │   ├── bfy.component.scss
│   │   ├── bfy.component.ts
│   │   ├── environment.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── system-config.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── typings.d.ts
├── tslint.json
└── typings.json
```

The `img` tag is at `/src/app/bfy.component.html` and the image itself is at `/public/book4u-logo.svg`.

Comment: `src/shared/assets/img/` makes sense for me.

Comment: It should be just `<img src="/book4u-logo.svg" />`.. Everything in `public/` is copied to `dist/` which is the "root folder" for your app..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Angular-cli` places all files in the `/dist` directory.

To display the image in index.html:
`<img src="book4u-logo.svg" />`

If you want to use your image in your app you should use a folder in the `/src` directory like `src/shared/assets/img/book4u-logo.svg`

The public folder is for public assets and the content is copied to the `/dist` folder.
However, when running `ng build --prod` the javascript in the`/public` folder is not copied over to `/dist`.

There is an open issue on Github:[Static JS assets not copying](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/540)
The image placed in the public folder should be accessible from the `dist` folder.

Answer (score 5):

Latest version of angular-cli(`angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3`) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag as below,
`<img src="./assets/logo.png">`

Note: When you build the project using `ng serve` it will copy your `assets` folder to `dist` folder.

Comment: makes it clear that you should use "./assets" rather "./src/..." ... spent ages scratching my head on this one...

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem in Angular 4 (I had a css file that was in public folder and I put it in assets folder). 
The answer would be:

- file path: ./src/assets/book4u-logo.svg
- `<img src="./assets/book4u-logo.svg>`